# Send data from an iOS app to an HTML5 website

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, post, google-sheets

I want to be able to send data from an iOS app (Objective-C) to an HTML5 website or Google spreadsheet or really anything where the data is accessible from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

What I highly reccomend is [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/), which can do exactly that easily with no server (you use Google's servers) and it's **free**. But, you have to know JavaScript (I can help a good amount because I just finished doing this)

I'm going to assume when you POST (what it's called when you give a server data, to simplify things) you want something back out (i.e. some [JSON](http://www.json.org/)) that says 'success' or gives more information back. Also, I'm going to forewarn you now: this is not for enterprise software - for that you want a real database and server (i.e. SQL or noSQL) but for sharing with other non-scripters, this gives you a built in shareable GUI (graphical user interface).

Okay, onto the code. Go to [script.google.com](https://www.script.google.com) and choose "Blank Project" on the left side. Now 3/4 of this code is going to be processing the request b/c adding a row to a google spreadsheet is literally one line(that's how powerful this is).

First, add this function in:

```javascript
function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.get) {
      Logger.log("GETing")
      //return getAsJSON()
  } else if (e.parameter.post) {
      Logger.log("POSTing")
      //return dopost(e)
  } else {
      //If don't do anything, get as JSON
      Logger.log("GETing")
      //return getAsJSON()
  }
}
```

Go to Run -> doGet and accept the popup for permissions (do this now and at the end or anytime it gives an error "Authorization is required to perform that action.")

Now, go to File -> Manage Versions -> Save New Version
Then Publish -> Deploy as Web App -> Make the project version the newest number and make sure it is "Execute the app as:" me and "Who has access to the app:" anyone (even anonymous).

Open the "Current web app URL: and the latest code" link underneath that.

That second link (latest code) should look something like https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxHk_GXziSAwSH6umVyz3LnnbgpkA9BnqvL2ILeF/dev. Add "?post=true" to the end of it and then refresh the page. Go back to the text editor page and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. You should see "POSTing"; replace "post" with "get" in the URL and refresh. Exit the "Logging Output" and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> again. You should see "GETing."

Almost there; now, the function `doPost`(first uncomment everything in the `doGet` function above except '//If don't do anything, get as JSON') and change your URL back to ?post from ?get. You were extremely unclear on what you wanted to add to your sheet so I'm going to assume you want to append a row with 2 cells. Add to the URL this:

```
&column1="TESTING"&column2="WOW"
```

What this is does is tell our code (1) we want to POST and (2) the new row should be TESTING, WOW (in different cells). Make a new Google spreadsheet and copy what's between "d/" and "/edit", put that in for spreadsheet and ID and put your email in; if something goes wrong it'll email you, so keep that open. The code is

```javascript
function doPost(e) {
    try {
        Logger.log(e)
        if (!(e.parameter.column1) || !(e.parameter.column2)) {
            MailApp.sendEmail("YOUR EMAIL HERE", "Problem with POST to gSheet", "Not correct parameters need column1 and column2 and both need to be '=something' ")
        } else {
            var allVals = SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR SPREADSHEET ID HERE").getActiveSheet().appendRow([e.parameter.column1, e.parameter.column2])
            return getAsJSON()
        }
    } catch (e) {
        MailApp.sendEmail("YOUR EMAIL HERE", "Problem with POST to gSheet", e)
    }
}
```

and `getASJSON` is

```javascript
function getAsJSON(){
    output = ContentService.createTextOutput()
    output.append("DONE")
    return output
}
```

It is very possible to return a JSON of your spreadsheet but that's beyond the scope of this and a good exercise.

Note: It will redirect you to a "googleusercontent" domain. If it does that, don't use that URL or refresh that one: go back to the /dev or /exec urls.

---

On the iOS side, all you have to do is make a POST request using the URL you constructed above, which is fairly simple. You mentioned Objective-C, but I'll provide Swift as well.

**Objective-C**:

```m
- (NSURLResponse *)POST:(NSString *)parameters {
    NSString *baseURL = @"https://script.google.com/macros/s/your_ID/dev?post=true";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [baseURL stringByAppendingString:parameters]]; // Set your URL here - don't forget to escape quotation marks when you pass the request parameters to the method

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    __block NSURLResponse *postResponse;
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        // What to do after the POST has completed (if the POST returns any data, it'll be stored in the response parameter specified above); use dispatch_async to wait until the request has completed
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            postResponse = response;
        });
    }];

    [dataTask resume];
    return postResponse;
}
```

**Swift**:

```swift
func POST(parameters: String) -> NSURLResponse? {
  let url: NSURL = NSURL(string:"https://script.google.com/macros/s/your_ID/dev?post=true\(parameters)")! // Set your URL here - don't forget to escape quotation marks when you pass the request parameters to the function

  let session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()      

  var postResponse: NSURLResponse?
  let dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in // Closure
    // What to do after the POST has completed (if the POST returns any data, it'll be stored in the response parameter specified above); use dispatch_async to wait until the request has completed
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
          postResponse = response
      })

  })

  dataTask.resume()
  return postResponse
}
```

Comment: And yes, to any confused readers, this was a combined effort. AstroCB and I had collaborated on a very similar project where I did the back end and he did the app front end. We thought we each could help

Comment: Wow thanks for the help! I'm not sure what this means, but when I try to run doGet, I get this error "TypeError: Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")"

Comment: Also just to clarify, on the sheet, I want a column of names of people with a number in the cell next to every person's name. I want the app to be able to add 1 to a certain person's number every time a certain event happens in the app. I'm not sure when I will be able to test the app because I am not yet enrolled in the apple developer program and the app relies on use of the device's camera which cannot be simulated. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: Does your url end in ?post=true&parameter1=hello&parameter2=world

Comment: We can do that increment next

Comment: Yes. This is what happens when I try to run doGet http://puu.sh/eohD1/16fd039c33.png

Comment: Go to https://script.google.com/d/1UhpaqJ1JrN2rPpHMos0UOAsmWIOkdNaW58foyJPASV6OOrAnh1Q2PdDJ/edit?usp=drive_web and https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Cb_R5n7TxOY1TcW4t8_FZWkthn4J4qc9_dv-bblfIqs/edit#gid=0 and make a copy; it should work

To prove that it does go to [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw5-QR234fuCT4A9b4srAaEWU1hpimgLYp6usJv3rzzqoFrCh4/exec?post=true&person=Hello%20World) to see it in action

Cheers!

Comment: Ok thanks. I won't really be able to do a ton more until I'm enrolled in the apple developer program because I'd like to test my app before doing much more with it. I'm creating this app for my school and I'm not sure when they will enroll me in the developer program.

Answer (score 0):

1. Code server to accept queries.
2. Code iOS app that queries server. Perhaps use AFNetworking.
3. Access data from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a page written in php that accept the data you send from the ios app, then the php sends the data to a server. The server contains a table with the rows that you want to populate.

Or you can use a back-end provider that does it for you, here is a [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20482/how-to-choose-the-best-backend-provider-for-your-ios-app-parse-vs-stackmob-vs-appcelerator-cloud-and-more) to explain how it works (from raywenderlich).